# how to run react using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is it possible to run react "out of the box" with  use of javascript only?

basically what i look for is a way to use react using nothing more than notepad to write the page. (no install and cofigure node etc..)

in more detail-
1) is there a standard built in replacement for node's statements such as -

require('react-dom');

require('MyExampleComponent'); 
etc...

2) a way to use jsx using an imported library or a replacment method, without the need to compile the jsx files into different js files.

here is an example of what i want to achieve:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     [import more required libraries if such exist]
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js">
    </script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body id="app">

</body>
</html>
```

1.js:

```
*[import script function]* ('react.js');
*[import script function]*('react-dom.js');
var testJsx=<h1>test</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(testJsx,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? I'd expect the console to report *Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined*

Comment: `var testJsx=<h1>test</h1>;` is not valid Javascript, it's JSX. You either need to include browser.js (like in the "external resources" of this JSFiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/ or use React.DOM.h1('test'); instead;

Comment: @Quentin true but not what i'm gunning at, Please take a look at the  edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to avoid using babel? Since you were using JSX, I don't think you can avoid Babel. But if you just want to have a minimal version of script to test out react, here it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="app">
        <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>test</h1>,document.getElementById("app"));     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats pretty much what im looking for, is there a way to make that work from within js files?

Comment: Yeah, i think only need to move anything between `<script type="text/babel">` and `</script>` to a file, and add src attribute, like  `<script type="text/babel" src="path-to-your-js">`

Comment: it does work, which leads to the final question - is there a built in replacement for node's export and require that i can use so i'll be able to use multiple component files that build on one another?

Comment: In the above case, you include `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>`, then you have access to an object ReactDOM.  Similarly, you are going to include many `<script type="text/babel" src="path-to-your-babel-js">` in your html, and each of them would export something to the global. You just need to use them in your javascript file, no need to "require".

Comment: Unfortunatlly i already tried that , for some reason it doesnt work. for example if i have 2 js files - 1.js contains var MyComponent=React.createClass({
    render:function (){
        return <h1>test component</h1>;
    }
});  and 2.js that contains var MyComponent1=React.createClass({
    render:function (){
        "use strict";
        return <MyComponent/>;
    }
})


ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent1/>,document.getElementById("app"));    the html that will use them both declare that myComponent is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The [`importScripts` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) is part of the Web Worker API and does not work the way you are trying to use it.

---

Besides that, the following line contains [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

```
var testJsx=<h1>test</h1>;
```

To use JSX, you need to include a compile step into your build process that turns it into valid JavaScript. Browsers cannot natively process JSX.

Comment: i know, i edited the question to reflect what i want to understand. basiclly is there a way to import scripts without node , and a way to use jsx